# How do I check if a post is private?

Tags: login, private, user-registration

What I am looking to do is check if a page is private, give the users the option to register and see the page. Here is what I have now:

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
    /* Print the most as normal */
else : 
  if ($post->post_status = 'private')
    { 
    /* Print login/register box */
    }
  else
    { 
    /* Print page not found message */
    }
endif; ?>
```

My problem is that it is always falling through and displaying the login box even when the page does not exists. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can we see the **full code** of your loop, please? Also: this is in the context of a static page, right?

Comment: Unless you are a time-traveler from 2004, skip the accepted answer and go straight for `get_post_status ( get_the_ID() )`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a POST is set to private, non-logged in users will receive a 404 message. If you dump the global variable `$wp_query`,

```
var_dump($wp_query);
```

..you will notice that no `post_status` is present in the parameters returned therefore using the slug (or `name` parameter of `query_vars` array for example) we can get the post status of the POST that is trying to be accessed like so,

```
global $wp_query;
$slug = $wp_query->query_vars['name'];
$status = get_page_by_path($slug, OBJECT, 'post');

if ($status->post_status == "private") {

     //show form

} else {

    //etc...

}
```

Helpful Codex resources:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path

## Update:

On the basis that you are trying to perform this action for the "PAGE" post type (as per your comments) the above code should change `'post'` to `'page'` accordingly in `get_page_by_path()`.

Now the reason why it still was not working while using `$wp_query->query_vars['name'];` is then related to the fact that your page is a CHILD page of another page, in otherwords it has a PARENT.

Because the function we are using is getting our page by its path, it needs to know its full path so the parent page matters. Therefore we must change,

```
$slug = $wp_query->query_vars['name'];
```

to

```
$slug = $wp_query->query['pagename']; //which will show the full path e.g. parent/child
```

Elaborating further what we are doing is accessing the full path from a different array within the `$wp_query` and here's an example (sample snippet) of what is `$wp_query` is actually comprised of when dumping the results

```
  ["query"]=>  //we are now accessing the ["query"] array instead of ["query_vars"]
  array(2) {
    ["page"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["pagename"]=> //and this is what need, notice the full path
    string(20) "sample-page/sub-page"
  }
  ["query_vars"]=>
  array(57) {
    ["page"]=>
    int(0)
    ["pagename"]=> //this is what we don't need, no full path contained, will not work
    string(8) "sub-page"
    etc.......
```

Therefore the modified code in full will look like;

```
global $wp_query;
$slug = $wp_query->query['pagename']; //from ->query_vars to ->query
$status = get_page_by_path($slug, OBJECT, 'page'); //change to meet your desired post_type

if ($status->post_status == "private") {

     //show form

} else {

    //etc...

}
```

As Kaiser mentioned you can also use, `get_post_status()` function to retrieve the post status and that can be done like so,

```
if (get_post_status($status->ID) == "private") ... etc
```

Comment: I got this working, except I am using the Custom Permalinks plugin. I'm pretty sure this is messing it up, because this does not work on the pages that I used the plugin to change the permalink. Is there a way to look this up by ID instead of slug? Thanks!

Comment: If you know the ID ahead of time then yes, which you could pass along in your `query_vars` or what would be simpler is to see what already exists within your `query_vars` for us to use (hence which is what the above method is doing). So if you can do, `var_dump($wp_query);` so we can see what is held in the global variable `$wp_query` for that page users are landing on (then copy your output to http://www.pastebin.com) so I can inspect the results so we get this working for you. Also when you say "pages" do you mean "page" or "post" because they are two different post types and the... (cont)

Comment: ...example shown using `get_page_by_path()` is set to the 'post' post_type. You'd need to change that to 'page' if you are working with a 'page' post_type and so on. Once we know more about your permalink structure (that's been created under the conditions/influence of that plugin) we'll be able to ascertain what specifically we can use to help you.

Comment: They are indeed pages versus posts, and I did change it from your example code. In looking at it more it doesn't seem to be interaction with the plugin, but whether it is a top level page. [Here](http://pastebin.com/8xAEb7PD) is the var_dump from [this page.](http://discerninghistory.com/about/test2/) It doesn't work, but [this does](http://discerninghistory.com/test_page) and [here](http://pastebin.com/B8AaTSF2) is it's var_dump. Thanks for your help!

Comment: My php code is [here](http://pastebin.com/WjqqaV36)

Comment: Change `$slug = $wp_query->query_vars['name'];` to `$slug = $wp_query->query['pagename'];` ... that should resolve your issue. (see my edit above for further explanation)

Comment: @userabuser FYI: [`get_post_status()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_post_status/) - better than accessing the global `$post`. Via QP ;)

Comment: @kaiser True, nicer to use the function, but another question for you; since we already used `get_page_by_path()` we have access to `post_status` held in our `$status` variable. Is it not inefficient to then be running `get_post_status()` which has to hit the DB again using `get_post()`? Still, added your suggestion to answer. Thanks for that :)

Comment: @userabuser [`get_post()` has a on-page cache](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.5/wp-includes/post.php#L577) right inside the call to the instance of `WP_Post`. :)

Answer (score 4):

Was just looking around for this answer myself in 2020 and it seems this is a great way to do it now.

```
<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php if ( get_post_status ( get_the_ID() ) == 'private' ) { ?>
      <h1>Private</h1>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```