# How to redirect non-logged in users to login with post_password_required()

Tags: filters, login, wp-redirect

I have created a membership site which is working how I would like in that non-members cannot view private pages.

However, I want that when someone who has not logged in, clicks on a link that links to a private page, they should be directed to my login page.

The closest I can figure out is using post_password_required(), but it doesn't seem to be working.

I don't want to hide the links from non-members.

```
function redirect_to_login() {
    if( post_password_required( get_the_ID() )  ) {
        wp_redirect( "index.php?p=50" );
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'redirect_to_login');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are using-- [`post_password_required`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_password_required)-- is true for ***password protected pages***, not for ***private*** pages. I am honestly not sure which you mean, but if you do mean "private" as in most of your description then...

I am not aware of an `is_private` function but you can check the post object itself. There is a catch though. "Private" posts are rabidly protected. A user without permissions to see the post will get a 404. I think the following will work, but due to the nature of "private" posts this may still be buggy. It has not been rigidly tested.

```
function redirect_to_login() {
  global $wp_query,$wpdb;
  if (is_404()) {
    $private = $wpdb->get_row($wp_query->request);
    if( 'private' == $private->post_status  ) {
      wp_safe_redirect(home_url(get_permalink(188)));
      die;
    }
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_login');
```

Comment: You are right, I mean pages that have the status set as 'private'. I tried the code you suggested in the functions.php file but it produces a white screen. When a non-logged in user clicks on a link to a 'private' page, currently the 404 page is showing. So I need to intercept this before the user is taken to the 404.

Comment: @tommyf : See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and I found a quite neat solution for it. When investigating, how Wordpress exactly handles the "Private-404" I found, that the post in question is in the queried_object. So you can actually check for that. Therefore in your 404.php do the following:

```
$queried = get_queried_object();
if (is_a($queried, 'WP_Post') && $queried->post_status == 'private') {
    // Set correct header
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden', true);
    // Show login form here or redirect to 
} else {
    // show 404-page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your header or appropriate template file:

```
$not_auth_redirect = get_permalink(8); // some page's id
if(!is_user_logged_in() && post_password_required(get_the_ID()) {
    wp_redirect( $not_auth_redirect );
}
```

You can set an ID to your home-page or some call to action page, then have the people redirected there if they are not logged in AND it is a password-required post.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I was going about it the wrong way. However I'm still having issues, the if statement isn't being triggered when it should & I think it's to do with the post_password_required. There are no posts only pages made private, does it also apply to pages as well as posts?

Comment: No, just the one function, which should work for pages as well. Try to trigger the condition on something else to see if it works. Like `if(1 == 1)`

Comment: Yes `if(1 == 1)` does trigger it. Also if I just use `!is_user_logged_in()` it triggers, which makes me think there's a problem with `post_password_required()`

Comment: Oops. I think we need the post's ID there. Try `post_password_required(get_the_ID())`

Comment: Unfortunately even with `get_the_ID()` it doesn't work. I think the solution cannot work from the head as the user has already been redirected to the 404 page before any of the 'private' page is output. I have to intercept the link click to the private page and take the user to the login page, presumably via functions.php.

Comment: See this answer for more information. You are talking about private anyway, not password protected. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78341/13676